# Can using Pandas read_csv alter the original file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Using this code to work with a dataset:

```
cities_orig = pd.read_csv("cities.csv")
```

I presume that now that cities_orig is assigned, I can alter that dataframe and the original csv file won't be changed. Am I correct? Are there exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct and there are no exceptions. The `read_csv` means to `read` the file and load into memory. Any changes to the in-memory variable does not change the actual csv file.